# What is an empty interface used for

Tags: interface, marker-interfaces

I am looking at nServiceBus and came over this interface

```
namespace NServiceBus
{
    public interface IMessage
    {
    }
}
```

What is the use of an empty interface?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Usually it's to signal usage of a class. You can implement IMessage to signal that your class is a message. Other code can then use reflection to see if your objects are meant to be used as messages and act accordingly.

This is something that was used in Java a lot before they had annotations. In .Net it's cleaner to use attributes for this.

---

@Stimpy77 Thanks! I hadn't thought of it that way.
I hope you'll allow me to rephrase your comment in a more general way.

Annotations and attributes have to be checked at runtime using reflection. Empty interfaces can be checked at compile-time using the type-system in the compiler. This brings no overhead at runtime at all so it is faster.

Comment: Be wary of the .NET comment, it requires reflection to use attributes, which is slower and does not support the "X is Y" and "X as Y" semantics. You can use empty interfaces in .NET too.

Comment: "This is something that was used in Java a lot before they had annotations." Could you clarify on this? I was thinking you meant there's an annotation you can use to achieve the same goal

Comment: From Effective Java (2017, Addison-Wesley) "You may hear it said that marker annotations (Item 39) make marker interfaces obsolete. This assertion is incorrect. Marker interfaces have two advantages over marker annotations. First and foremost, marker interfaces define a type that is implemented by instances of the marked class; marker annotations do not... Another advantage of marker interfaces over marker annotations is that they can be targeted more precisely...."

Answer (score 25):

Also known as a [Marker Interface](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

Answer (score 15):

In java `Serializable` is the perfect example for this. It defines no methods but every class that "implements" it has to make sure, that it is really serializable and holds no reference to things that cannot be serialized, like database connections, open files etc.

Comment: And that you bettter add the serialVersionUID

Comment: if Serializable is empty...how is that enforced?

Comment: Source note - response comes from reading Item 14 of Effective Java (2017 Addison-Wesley)

@TimBoland I'm thinking about three scenarios:
1. You have a method `serialize(Object o)` - in this case, the compiler knows nothing about o, and the programmer has no help from the compiler to enforce any property
2. You have `serialize(Serializable s)` - in this case, the compiler knows *something* - it won't accept any old Object. The compiler reminds the programmer to enforce the property associated with the `Serializable` interface in the classes that implement it.

Comment: 3. You update `Serializable` to have a `String serializeMe()` method. And, you have again `serialize(Serializable b)`. Now, the compiler reminds the programmer to enforce the property in two ways - as before, it reminds the programmer to enforce that property for all arguments to `serialize`. Unlike before, it also requires the programmer to implement the `serializeMe()` method. The intention, of course, is that the property associated to `Serializable` is present in and only in the implementation of `serializeMe()`. But, whether or not that happens is up to the programmer.

Answer (score 12):

In Java, empty interfaces were usually used for "tagging" classes - these days annotations would normally be used.

It's just a way of adding a bit of metadata to a class saying, "This class is suitable for `<this>` kind of use" even when no common members will be involved.

Comment: Hm sounds like either a misuse of the concept or a smart idea. Probably both ;-).

Comment: Before annotations, it was somewhat reasonable. Now there's no good reason to use it, IMO.

Answer (score 2):

Normally it's similar to attributes. Using attributes is a preferred to empty interfaces (at least as much as FxCop is aware). However .NET itself uses some of these interfaces like `IRequiresSessionState` and `IReadOnlySessionState`. I think there is performance loss in metadata lookup when you use attributes that made them use interfaces instead.

Comment: A major difference between marker interfaces and attributes is that a class which implements a marker interfaces commits all descendent classes to doing so, while a class which contains an attribute imposes no such requirement on its descendents.  If it's important to be able to define classes which don't do something their base class does, use attributes.  If recipients of of a reference need to rely upon any passed instance supporting any feature that the reference type does, use marker interfaces.

Answer (score 2):

An empty interface acts simply as a placeholder for a data type no better specified in its interface behaviour.

In Java, the mechanism of the interface extension represents a good example of use. For example, let's say that we've the following

```
interface one {}
interface two {}

interface three extends one, two {}
```

Interface three will inherit the behaviour of 'one' and 'two', and so

```
class four implements three { ... }
```

has to specify the two methods, being of type 'three'.

As you can see, from the above example, empty interface can be seen also as a point of multiple inheritance (not allowed in Java).

Hoping this helps to clarify with a further viewpoint.

Answer (score 1):

They're called "Mark Interfaces" and are meant to signal instances of the marked classes.

For example... in C++ is a common practice to mark as "ICollectible" objects so they can be stored in generic non typed collections.

So like someone over says, they're to signal some object supported behavior, like ability to be collected, serialized, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Empty interfaces are used to document that the classes that implement a given interface have a certain behaviour

For example in java the `Cloneable` interface in Java is an empty interface. When a class implements the `Cloneable` interface you know that you can call run the `clone()` on it.

Comment: Why not just have`clone` inside `Cloneable`?

Answer (score 1):

Been working with **NServiceBus** for the past year.  While I wouldn't speak for **Udi Dahan** my understanding is that this interface is indeed used as a **marker** primarily.

Though I'd suggest you ask the man himself if he'd had thoughts of leaving this for future extension.  My bet is no, as the mantra seems to be to keep messages very simple or at least practically platform agnostic.

Others answer well on the more general reasons for empty interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say its used for "future" reference or if you want to share some objects, meaning you could have 10 classes each implementing this interface.

And have them sent to a function for work on them, but if the interface is empty, I'd say its just "pre"-work.

Answer (score 0):

Empty interfaces are used to mark the class, at run time type check can be performed using the interfaces.

For example 
  An application of marker interfaces from the Java programming language is the Serializable interface. A class implements this interface to indicate that its non-transient data members can be written to an ObjectOutputStream. The ObjectOutputStream private method writeObject() contains a series of instanceof tests to determine writeability, one of which looks for the Serializable interface. If any of these tests fails, the method throws a NotSerializableException.

Answer (score 0):

An empty interface can be used to classify classes under a specific purpose. (**Marker Interface**)

**Example : Database Entities**

```
public interface IEntity {

}

public class Question implements IEntity {
   // Implementation Goes Here
}

public class Answer implements IEntity {
   // Implementation Goes Here
}
```

For Instance, If you will be using Generic Repository(ex. **IEntityRepository**), using generic constraints, you can prevent the classes that do not implement the IEntity interface from being sent by the developers.