# How to use an interface as parameter of other interface with multiple implementations?

Tags: java

I am trying to fix this.

There is a public interface **StudentValidation** that has this method:

```
default public void validateStudent(ObjectA inputA){};
default public void validateStudent(ObjectB inputB, ObjectC inputC){};
```

and it has implementations in two different classes.

So I have

**ValidatorStudentSchoolBased** that process the value for **validateStudent(ObjectA inputA)...**

and

**ValidateStudentsHomeBased** that process **validateStudent(ObjectB inputB, ObjectC inputC)**

So right now the common interface makes not so much sense and I was wondering if there is any strategy, interface/implementation that I could use for this case so I could be able to send one just parameter like

```
default public void validateStudent(MyObject myObject)
```

So far I created MyObject -> StudentClass as an empty interface [What is an Empty interface used for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/380665/what-is-an-empty-interface-used-for) and with two specific implementation that are according the needs

So I did this

```
public interface StudentClass {}
```

and then

```
public class StudentClassSchoolBased implements StudentClass () {
   ObjectA inputA;

//getters and setters

}
```

I will also create the implementation **StudentHomeBased**

Then edited StudentValidation like

```
validateStudent(StudentClass myObject)
```

And change the implementations like:

```
ValidatorStudentSchoolBased(StudentClassHomeBased myObject)
```

Says does not match the interface (and I cannot override) due the type of the interface is **StudentClass** and even if **StudentClassHomeBased** implements it, does not the trick, any idea of how to do what I am trying to do?

Basically, what I want to do is this

create an interface method that as parameter receives another interface with multiple implementations, is that possible?

Comment: Sorry, but there's a lot going on here and I can't work out exactly what your error is and on what code it applies.  Can you please [edit] to clarify?

Comment: Where did you put `default public void doSomething(MyInterface myInterface )`?

Comment: In general, the purpose of an interface is to ensure that **all** implementations of it can handle the data that the interface expects. Therefore, implementorA and implementorB should not process different methods. Both implementations need to define both methods.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I just updated it, please take a look @JoeC

Comment: @aka-one please take a look

Comment: thanks @JakeLawrence for the suggest, unfortunately for this I cannot have both implementations both implementing the methods but I want at least to have same parameter as entry

Comment: @jgpanz18 I'm still unclear on the exact nature of your problem. For what reason do you want to be able to pass the two different methods the same parameter? Could you perhaps edit your post again and add a snippet of what code is currently throwing the error, and an example of code you want to be able to write in order to use your two classes?

Comment: Edited, please take a look

Answer (score 0):

I think your case can be resolved by using generics and parametrizing `StudentValidation`. 
Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
public interface StudentValidation<T>{
    public void validateStudent(T student);
}

public class ValidatorStudentSchoolBased implements 
StudentValidation<StudentClassSchoolBased>{

    @Override
    public void validateStudent(StudentClassSchoolBased student) {

    }
}

public class ValidateStudentsHomeBased implements 
StudentValidation<StudentClassHomeBased>{

    @Override
    public void validateStudent(StudentClassHomeBased student) {

    }
}
```